# Flutter App stuck on "app running gradle task 'assembledebug..."

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter, mobile

This is my first flutter app I tried running the sample given by the flutter but it gets stuck on this message app  `running gradle task 'assembledebug....` or after sometime error `Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1` appears.
Tried doing all the things answered in similar questions. Using sdk version 30, Android studio ver 3.1 and flutter ver 1.20.1.

```
> Failed to transform artifact 'x86_debug.jar (io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-c8e3b9485386425213e2973126d6f57e7ed83c54)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\dell\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\x86_debug\1.0.0-c8e3b9485386425213e2973126d6f57e7ed83c54\570a59b7be41f73458509975d3eefca7ad5561cf\x86_debug-1.0.0-c8e3b9485386425213e2973126d6f57e7ed83c54.jar.
         > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\dell\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\x86_debug\1.0.0-c8e3b9485386425213e2973126d6f57e7ed83c54\570a59b7be41f73458509975d3eefca7ad5561cf\x86_debug-1.0.0-c8e3b9485386425213e2973126d6f57e7ed83c54.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: can you please show me error

Comment: after running few more times Build is now failing...Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1. This is the message

Comment: That doesn't help, copy and paste the other lines before that into your question

Comment: Did you try file>Invailde cache restart

Comment: Tried Invalidate cache/Restart

Comment: Question edited..Pasted the error message in the question

Answer (score 5):

Run

```
flutter run -v
```

so you can see which part is taking much time.
**In my case** it was
`Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip`
if you have the same problem [check this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/73852)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried a clean build with `flutter clean`? and could you also post more of your error and code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to empty cache "C:\Users\dell.gradle\caches" and re-run the project. You should also check for Event log error when building the project.

Answer (score 0):

In your android studio, cd to android directory then run from terminal:
gradlew clean
gradlew build
and then run the application.
If it wont work try flutter clean.
Also delete the .gradle folder in Users directory.
it will take some time but it will run.